# loop through a list and use previous elements

Tags: python

I have a list that contains decimal numbers, however in this example I use ints:

```
my_list = [40, 60, 100, 240, ...]
```

I want to print each element of the list in reverse order and afterwards I want to print a second line where every value is divided by 2, then a third line where the previous int is devided by 3 and so on...

Output should be:

```
240     120     60     36
120      60     30     18  #previous number divided by 2
 40      20     10      6  #previous number divided by 3
...     ...     ...    ... #previous number divided by 4 ...
```

My solution is ugly: I can make a slice and reverse that list and make n for loops and append the result in a new list. But there must be a better way. How would you do that?

Comment: I changed your variable name since `list` shadows the builtin `list`

Comment: How far down is it supposed to go? Does it stop at divided by 4? 50?

Comment: maximum is 20, not more.

Comment: Where do you get `120` and `36`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd write a generator to yield lists in turn:

```
def divider(lst,n):
    lst = [float(x) for x in lst[::-1]]
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        lst = [x/i for x in lst]
        yield lst
```

is more appropriate.  If we want to make it slightly more efficient, we could factor out the first iteration (division by 1) and yield it separately:

```
def divider(lst,n):
    lst = [float(x) for x in reversed(lst)]
    yield lst
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        lst = [x/i for x in lst]
        yield lst
```

*Note that in this context there isn't a whole lot of difference between `lst[::-1]` and `reversed(lst)`.  The former is typically a little faster, but the latter is a little more memory efficient.  Choose according to your constraints.

---

Demo:

```
>>> def divider(lst,n):
...     lst = [float(x) for x in reversed(lst)]
...     yield lst
...     for i in range(2,n+1):
...         lst = [x/i for x in lst]
...         yield lst
... 
>>> for lst in divider([40, 60, 100, 240],3):
...     print lst
... 
[240.0, 100.0, 60.0, 40.0]
[120.0, 50.0, 30.0, 20.0]
[40.0, 16.666666666666668, 10.0, 6.666666666666667]
```

Comment: @jamylak -- Thanks.  I'm gonna need to remember that little piece of markup :)

Comment: ...Although in Python 2 you'll have to start with a list of floats for "regular division" to work as expected.

Comment: I don't think the subsequent divisions are meant to be in reversed order.

Comment: @Volatility -- Yep.  "regular division" being whatever function gets called by the `/` operator.

Comment: @HennyH -- Why not?  It seems to be that way in the example.  (admittedly, OP's example isn't that great since it appears that 100 -> 120 and 40 -> 36).

Comment: @mgilson I can't use normal division or int division because I'm using decimal numbers. Is is possible to divide x/i to get a decimal number in the end?

Comment: @Johnny -- If they start as floats and you do `x/i`, you'll end up with floats.  If they start as floats and integers, then you can make sure they start as floats in the first line:  `lst = map(float,reversed(lst))` instead of `lst = lst[::-1]`.

Comment: @mgilson You're right, sorry, my interpretation of his written question was wrong, I thought the reversing was once off.

Answer (score 2):

To print the columnar the output you want, use [format strings](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language). You may have to tweak this to get the alignment and precision you want for your actual data:

```
def print_list(L):
    print '    '.join('{:>3d}'.format(i) for i in L)
```

Normally to do the division we could use a function with recursion, but we can also use a simple loop where each iteration produces the list that is worked on next:

```
my_list = [40, 60, 100, 240, 36, 60, 120, 240]

maxdiv = 20
baselist = list(reversed(my_list))
for div in range(1, maxdiv+1):
    baselist = [i/div for i in baselist]
    print_list(baselist)
```

Output:

```
240    120     60     36    240    100     60     40
120     60     30     18    120     50     30     20
 40     20     10      6     40     16     10      6
 10      5      2      1     10      4      2      1
  2      1      0      0      2      0      0      0
  0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
  0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
  0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
max_n = 3
vals  = [40, 60, 100, 240]
grid  = [list(reversed(vals))]

for n in xrange(2, max_n + 1):
    grid.append([v/n for v in grid[-1]])

for g in grid:
    print g

# Output
[240, 100, 60, 40]
[120.0, 50.0, 30.0, 20.0]
[40.0, 16.666666666666668, 10.0, 6.666666666666667]
```

Comment: A few comments.  1) This isn't correct.  You're dividing the original list by n at each iteration rather than dividing the most recently computed list by n.  2) (this one is minor) You're reversing the list over and over which is inefficient.  3) You could probably change the outer list comprehension to a generator.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_list = my_list[::-1] #reverse the list
print '\t'.join(map(str, new_list))
for _counter in range(2, 21): #count from 2 to 20
    for _index in range(len(new_list)): # iterate the whole list
        new_list[_index] = new_list[_index]/_counter
        print '\t'.join(map(str, new_list))
```

Which will produce an output like(I used `float` instead of `int`):

```
240.0       100.0         60.0         40.0
120.0        50.0         30.0         20.0
40.0        16.6666666667 10.0         6.66666666667
10.0        4.16666666667 2.5          1.66666666667
2.0         0.833333333333 0.5         0.333333333333
```

Answer (score -2):

```
my_list = [40, 60, 100, 240]
def dostuff(l,limit):
    print('\t'.join(map(str,reversed(l))))
    print('\n'.join([ '\t'.join(map(str,[v/float(i) for v in reversed(my_list)])) for i in range(2,limit+1)]))
dostuff(my_list,20)
```

Produces:

```
240 100 60  40
120.0   50.0    30.0    20.0
80.0    33.333333333333336  20.0    13.333333333333334
60.0    25.0    15.0    10.0
48.0    20.0    12.0    8.0
40.0    16.666666666666668  10.0    6.666666666666667
34.285714285714285  14.285714285714286  8.571428571428571   5.714285714285714
30.0    12.5    7.5 5.0
26.666666666666668  11.11111111111111   6.666666666666667   4.444444444444445
24.0    10.0    6.0 4.0
21.818181818181817  9.090909090909092   5.454545454545454   3.6363636363636362
20.0    8.333333333333334   5.0 3.3333333333333335
18.46153846153846   7.6923076923076925  4.615384615384615   3.076923076923077
17.142857142857142  7.142857142857143   4.285714285714286   2.857142857142857
16.0    6.666666666666667   4.0 2.6666666666666665
15.0    6.25    3.75    2.5
14.117647058823529  5.882352941176471   3.5294117647058822  2.3529411764705883
13.333333333333334  5.555555555555555   3.3333333333333335  2.2222222222222223
12.631578947368421  5.2631578947368425  3.1578947368421053  2.1052631578947367
12.0    5.0 3.0 2.0
```

Comment: Look at the OP's expected output. You're printing the lists backwards.